# Page 404 error on clicking at the image link in django admins site

Tags: django, image, post, django-rest-framework, get

We have a django project in which we are storing images in the backend using image field.The image link is being stored on django admin site.However ,when I click on the link ,I get an error page.Here's my code.
***models.py***

```
  images=models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to,null=True)

    def upload_to(instance, filename):
        return 'images/{filename}'.format(filename=filename)
```

***urls.py***

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('app/',include('firstapp.urls')),
    path('',include('firstapp.api.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

***settings.py***

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media')

# URL used to access the media
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

---

I have created a folder named media but the images are not being stored there.Please help.

Comment: please provide traceback

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media') #Just add like this
```

Do pass directly to field instead of creating function of uploat_to.

```
images=models.ImageField(upload_to="images/",null=True)
```

Do above things and see if it solves.

Do reply if it is not solved.

Answer (score 0):

From **Python Doc.**  [**`os.path.dirname(...)`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname)

> Return the directory name of pathname path. This is the first element
> of the pair returned by passing path to the function [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split).

[**`os.path.join()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) takes first argument as full path becouse of this your **MEDIA_ROOT** is giving wrong path.
If you're using `Django>=3.0` version then you can use [**`pathlib`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) like this

```
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```